# Encrypt DateField in django models?

Tags: django-models

I am having a requirement that i have to encrypt some of the fields in a table.
I am using Django 1.3.1 and postgres 9.1. I am referring to this app django-fields :-

https://github.com/svetlyak40wt/django-fields/blob/master/src/django_fields/fields.py

Here is my code :-

```
patient_type = EncryptedCharField(max_length=80, choices=CHOICES.PATIENT_TYPES)
date_of_birth = EncryptedDateField(null=True, blank=True)
gender = EncryptedCharField(max_length=1024, choices=CHOICES.GENDERS, blank=True)
contact_phone = EncryptedCharField(max_length=1024, blank=True)
security_question = models.ForeignKey(SecurityQuestion, null=True, blank=True)
security_answer = EncryptedCharField(max_length=1024, null=True, blank=True)
```

It stores everything in encrypted form in the database except date_of_birth.It throws this error

Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/user/slave/old_careprep/CPMS-Source/careprep/../careprep/utilities/decorators.py" in _dec
  14.             return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/slave/old_careprep/CPMS-Source/careprep/../careprep/visit/views.py" in setup
  202.                 patient.save()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  460.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  553.                     result = manager._insert(values, return_id=update_pk, using=using)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  195.         return insert_query(self.model, values, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1436.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  791.         cursor = super(SQLInsertCompiler, self).execute_sql(None)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  735.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  34.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py" in execute
  44.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

Exception Type: DatabaseError at /visit/setup/
Exception Value: invalid input syntax for type date: "$AES$55403376ed906e119b0f7779554fbb51"
LINE 1: ...L, NULL, '$AES$0452edae035cc33c4084e7b0fb39edd7', '$AES$5540...
                                                             ^
Help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that i was using DateField earlier if i convert DateField to CharField and then apply EncryptedCharField it solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

**Solution in short**

***Use custom encryption fields***

Here's an example for `EncryptedCharField` and `EncryptedDateField`

```
class EncryptedCharField(CharField):
    def _get_cipher(self):
        return Fernet(SECRET_KEY)   

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        cipher = self._get_cipher()
        if value:
            return cipher.decrypt(value.encode()).decode()
        return value

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value:
            cipher = self._get_cipher()
            return cipher.encrypt(value.encode()).decode()
        return value


class EncryptedDateField(DateField):
    def _get_cipher(self):
        return Fernet(SECRET_KEY)

    def to_python(self, value: Any) -> Any:
        cipher = self._get_cipher()
        if value:
            date = cipher.decrypt(value.encode()).decode()
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        return value

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        return self.to_python(value)
        
    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value:
            cipher = self._get_cipher()
            return cipher.encrypt(str(value).encode()).decode()
        return value

    def get_internal_type(self):
        return "TextField"
```

**Explaination** -

Data in CharFields are expected to be strings, when you're using `EncryptedCharField` the encrypted data is being stored as string in database.

for eg. in field `gender` value (`Male`) will be stored in encrypted form `gAAAAABktoZJ-fQdjJH4OgPs3riR2Fg6vqgUhduunXMW3pAYwJ47j1rhAUeXH5dTwT1ZlurteqTpUlm9p8oLJg34hPd5XTtubA==`

when you fetch data for this particular value you get `gAAAAABktoZJ-fQdjJH4OgPs3riR2Fg6vqgUhduunXMW3pAYwJ47j1rhAUeXH5dTwT1ZlurteqTpUlm9p8oLJg34hPd5XTtubA==`
and then you decrypt it.

in case of `date_of_birth` field, when you try to encrypt data it will break, because encryption algorithms works on bytes type.

for fields expecting strings `(CharField or TextField)`
**`encode -> encrypt -> decode -> save`**.

for fields like `DateTime, JSONField, BooleanField` etc.

**`convert in string -> encode -> encrypt -> decode -> save`**.